# Adding Domain User to Local Admin Group

Tags: windows

I have an Azure VM that's confusing me on some points:

1. I have a domain user that I added to the local admin group
2. That user still doesn't seem to be having admin privileges.
3. I also added the user to the domain admin group -- still no luck.

I still have to right click an app and select Run as Admin to perform admin commands like *iisreset*.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Azure. There is nothing azure-specific.

Answer (score 5):

You misunderstand UAC. Adding a user to an Admin group gives the user the ability to launch a process with admin privileges. It does not start every process with admin privileges.